# My homepage wont go through HTTPS port

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

So my domain is [1] and as you can see whenever you go on that link it will get HTTP (without padlock) but if you go to any other link it will be HTTPS. Only my homepage goes through HTTP.

Important things to mention is that I use Apache.
Every my attempt to edit `.htaccess` file ends up by website stoping to work. My whole website is hosted on AWS and that is where I derived my SSL certificate.

I want to make that homepage load in HTTPS as well. 
How should I do that?
[Here is my app folder and place where I created my .htaccess file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U637N.jpg).

[1]:

Comment: Please post your question on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your `.htaccess` should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.urtina.com/ [L,R=301]
```

If it breaks Apache, check the error log. It is for the homepage only as requested.

Comment: I created my .htacess file and I think .htacess is causing an issue here.
Since I created it on my own I want to know where should .htaccess file be placed. 

I tried putting your code inside the .htaccess file and  the browser gives me the error because of too much redirects.

Comment: Sure, just add it to your question and we'll see what's going on.

Comment: As you can see. 
Whenever you go to 

www.urtina.com or urtina.com - it gives you unsecured content without the green lock on the address bar.
But whenever you go to any other page it gives you https website.